# How to hold for 5 sec after api response and then go next in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, facebook-graph-api

Here in my code in "registrationRequest" i am getting api response after that I am updating state , on that flag some popup I am showing , but in my code after response I have to navigate other page . So i just want to wait for 5 sec after respone and then go to next .

```
let registrationRequest = _.get(data, 'registrationRequest') || {};
                console.log("updateeeee 3", registrationRequest);
                this.setState ({
                    isWalletCreation:false,
                    isWalletCreationDone:true
                })
```

////////// 5 sec delay here and then move to below code /

```
if (!_.isEmpty(registrationRequest)) {
                let stages = await getData(WORK_FLOW_STAGES);
                let WorkFlowStages = JSON.parse(stages);
                WorkFlowStages.isProductConfigured = 'true'
                registrationData.configureProductValues = this.state.configureProductValues;
                await writeToCache(this,
                    FETCH_CACHE_OFFER_DETAILS,
                    {
                        data: registrationData,
                    }
                );
                await storeData(IS_WALLET_ACTIVE, JSON.stringify(this.state.isWalletEnable));
                await storeData(WORK_FLOW_STAGES, JSON.stringify(WorkFlowStages));
                this.props.navigation.navigate("CustomerRegistrationDetailsContainer");

            }
```

Comment: Hey, why would you need a 5 second delay? Is that so you can get your response within those 5 seconds? Its not a best practise to wait like that so use promises.Once you get the response you move to the if statement bellow. Pretty sure most of the data fetching APIs ( axios, fetch etc.) are made async

Comment: after response  i am making isWalletCreation:false, and   "isWalletCreationDone:true"
ton that I have to display one modal . ,but after reponse is navigating so not able to display that

Comment: As far as I see here you didn't resolve your response whatsoever so the console.log and all code bellow it will execute even before the response
Not saying this is your problem, but something you should keep an eye out for
How can your response be navigating you to somewhere?

Comment: this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("CustomerRegistrationDetailsContainer");
                    // Add your logic for the transition
               }, 3000);

Answer (score 1):

It was very simple , actually I got confused ,its working ..

```
  this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
                        this.props.navigation.navigate("CustomerRegistrationDetailsContainer");
                        // Add your logic for the transition
                   }, 4000);
```